# Batch Matrix Multiplication with sparse Tensors in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, parallel-processing, gpu, sparse-matrix, multiplication

Is there a way to perform the Batch Matrix Multiplication in Tensorflow but using SparseTensors?
I know that there isn't a explicit function to do this, but I was wondering if it's possible to do it using a tf.map_fn.

An example of how I'd explicitly for-loop is shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

adj_split = [tf.sparse.SparseTensor(indices=[[0, 1], [1, 6]], values=[1.0, 2.0], dense_shape=[10, 10]) for _ in range(5)]
adj_dense = tf.stack([tf.sparse.to_dense(adj_sp) for adj_sp in adj_split])
mu = tf.random.uniform(shape=[5, 10, 7])
mu_split = tf.unstack(mu, axis = 0)

original_result = tf.einsum('ivu, iuk->ivk', adj_dense, mu) # Batch Matrix Multiply

result_list = []
for i in range(len(adj_split)):
  result_list.append(tf.sparse.sparse_dense_matmul(adj_split[i], mu_split[i]) )

for_loop_result = tf.stack(result_list, axis = 0)

original_result == for_loop_result # True
```

However, I'm not sure if Tensorflow will automatically parallelize these independent for loops - If not, is there a way to do this using tf.map_fn? I'm having trouble applying tf.map_fn since it seems like it does't allow operations of the form [a1,a2,a3], [b1,b2,b3] -> [f(a1,b1), f(a2,b2), f(a3,b3)].